# Three.js limit pan in OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three.js, wow do I add or put limits on how far left/right/up/down a user can pan when using OrbitControls? I'd prefer not to be able to pan so far away that you are unable to see the objects in the scene.

Comment: You have to write the code to do that yourself.

Comment: Any help on how one would go about this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't write your code for you. Try something, and if you have problems, show a live example, and ask a specific question about it. `OrbitControls` is part of the examples, not the library, so you are free to modify it to your liking.

Comment: hmm, as panning moves the camera target in OrbitControls, you could modify orbitcontrols to check if the target is moved inside a predefined radius around the coordinate center? And if it would be leaving this radius, stop panning? :) Not sure how the user feedback will be with limited pan but yo ucould try this way :)

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of OrbitControls.js, the position is updated with the panning changes [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/bde2a91316041e39a198d92255c701d4020bf4d4/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L310).

Now if you want to limit the panning to some boundaries, you can simply check if the new position of the camera lies within this boundaries, otherwise you do not update the position:

```
var newX = this.target.x + pan.x;
var newY = this.target.y + pan.y;
if (newX <= this.maxXPan && newX >= this.minXPan 
        && newY <= this.maxYPan && newY >= this.minYPan) {
    this.target.add( pan );
}
```